# debugging list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, lazy-evaluation

I copied the Euler.11 solution given on
 ( http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Euler_problems/11_to_20#Problem_11), but it fails with an indexing error: " *(Array.!): undefined array element*".
Of course firstly I'd like a better error message(!), perhaps even giving the failed index, but failing that I tried to debug it.

The data is input correctly, and a print of it shows the right bounds, and data.

So I added a few trace messages, to both the result expression, and the body of the comprehension. I get lots of trace results from the final expression, but none from the body computations. Why?

```
prods :: Array (Int, Int) Int -> [Int]
-- trace ("xs: " ++ show xs) (product xs)
prods a = [trace ("xs: " ++ show xs) (product xs) | i <- range $ bounds a,
                        s <- senses,
                        let trace1 = check "i: " i,
                        let is = take 4 $ iterate s i,
                        let trace2 = check "is: " is,
                        all (inArray a) is,
                        let xs = map (a!) is]

-- Doit
-- euler = print . maximum . prods . input =<< getContents
euler eData = maximum . prods $ input eData

-- Debugging tracecheck :: String -> a -> a
check msg v | trace (msg ++ (show v)) True = v
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, making the error message include the failing index would require the `Show` constraint to be added to the array indices, which may be undesired.

Second, as Roman said, the messages are not printed because of lazy evaluation. Bang-patterns  (`let !trace = check "i: " i`) may be the most convenient way to circumvent it, but I don't know exactly how those work inside of list comprehensions.

Next, the `undefined array element` message tells you that the array was constructed incorrectly (some elements were left undefined), so you need to debug the function constructing it rather than the function using it.

Comment: Many thanks on all points; seems obvious (now!). I did print the array after constructing it, and it all looked good, with the expected bounds. I'll play with it a bit more to see if/how it got some undefined values.

Comment: You're right about the bad setup of data - I had misinterpreted the error message.

Answer (score 5):

Haskell is a lazy language(*). You do not *use* `trace1` and `trace2` in your computation, hence they are not evaluated, and nothing gets printed.

For example, if you replace

```
let is = take 4 $ iterate s i
```

with

```
let is = take 4 $ iterate s trace1
```

then `trace1` will be used and should lead to tracing messages.

(*) More precisely, GHC, the Haskell implementation most used today, uses lazy evaluation to achieve Haskell's non-strict semantics. Never mind if this doesn't make sense.